# Meteor change userId in users collection

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app needs to change the currently logged in userId to a different unique id in the users collection.

The current code changes the userId on the client side as shown in the browser console but the did not change the userId in the users collection as shown in 
mongo-shell.
Any idea what I need to do to change the value of `_id` in the users collection for the currently logged in user? thx

```
//----client.js
Meteor.call('changeUserId', myUniqueUserId, () => {
  Meteor.connection.setUserId(myUniqueUserId);

});

//----server.js
'changeUserId': (myUniqueUserId) => {
  this.setUserId(myUniqueUserId);
  return true;
},
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

User is a collection.

You can manipulate it as a regular collection, so either:

- Do a `Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set:{_id:<newid>}});` assuming you setup the collections update permissions correctly for the user collection.
- Make a Meteor.method that you call from the client that does the update.

Comment: I will do this in the server method I posted but does it go before or after `this.serUserId(myUniqueUserId);` is called?

Comment: I would do it after, but I am not sure. Actually setUserId is not well documented... Sorry you will have to test.